# Base page gets expires when i close the modal window

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wicketstuff

i have page from this page i am calling new  modal window page . now i have cancel button on this modal page . 
cancel.Onclick  simply says -

window.close(AjaxRequestTarget)

then base page remains for a moment then page gets expire .
any help ?

Comment: Maybe, if you'd share some more information, like the part of your page that creates the ModalWindow or the contents of your ModalWindow...

Comment: Ahh. i got the remedy for this . well actually my base was not serialized properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh. i got the remedy for this . well actually my base was not serialized properly –